# Beautiful soup is not limiting the result in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, beautifulsoup

I was creating a script to fetch me the new episodes from funimation. So, I wrote this simple script.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess     



r = requests.get('http://www.funimation.com/videos/episodes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.title
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'item-resume-info clearfix'})
for show in subtitles:
  x = show.find_all('a', limit=1)
  for a in x:
   url = a['href']
   file = open("LatestLink.txt", "w")
   file.write(url)
   file.close()
```

as you can see it fetches the contents from hompage and shows me the link. It is working and giving me links.But, it's giving me all the links. Even though I limited the output, it still shows 20 links. Why is that happening?And when I write it to the file, it prints just one link and of the oldest release on their page.

How do I either order the results or limit them to 1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is giving you one `a` tag from each element so you are not getting all them which you can see if you `print(len(x))` with `limit=1` and without:

```
In [29]: for show in subtitles:
   ....:       x = show.find_all('a',limit=1)
   ....:       print(len(x))
   ....:     
1
1
1
1
1
1
.............

In [30]: for show in subtitles:
      x = show.find_all('a')
      print(len(x))
   ....:     
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
..................
```

If you add a count and increment in your loop you can also verify you get 20 urls with `limit=1` and 40 without. Your first findAll returns 20 elements, you iterate over each one and extract the `a` tag each time so you are getting exactly what you should be getting.

For your file issue you only see one link in your file because you keep **overwriting** using `w`, open the file once outside the loop:

```
with  open("LatestLink.txt", "w") as f:
    for show in subtitles:
        x = show.find_all('a', limit=1)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url)
```

If you actually only want the first `item-resume-info clearfix` to get a single link then use find instead of findAll,`.find` will return the first `.findAll` returns all.

```
subtitles = soup.find('div', {'class': 'item-resume-info clearfix'})
with  open("LatestLink.txt", "w") as f:
        url = subtitles.a["href"]
        f.write(url)
```

Which returns `http://www.funimation.com/shows/chaos-dragon/videos/official/antinomy`, the first result on the page.

Comment: the thing is that I just want one URL out of these 20 urls... the one at the top.. and I'm a beginner in python... So, please go easy on me a bit...

Comment: Then you should be using find `subtitles = soup.find('div', {'class': 'item-resume-info clearfix'}) url = subtitles.a["href"]`